# Product Special Price with hh:mm:ss

Tags: magento-1.9, date, special-price, time

How to add hh:mm:ss for the special price date in magento.1.9?

Comment: means you want to add some `hour / minutes / seconds` to `special price date` product attribute at frontend ?

Comment: Yes. which i need to set in product special price along with date

Comment: There are `PHP` methods available for `add/remove` `hour/minutes/seconds`, like: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+5 hours'));`